# Phonegap plugins and Xcode not finding in config

Tags: xml, xcode, apache, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to build my app but it's not finding any of the plugins since the new update, I've fiddled around so much with my configs that i'm beginning to lose track of what i'm doing. I have all my plugins in the folder :

[image]

and in my config file :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mycom" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hilton Smythe</name>
    <description>
        Hilton Smythe Consultancy App
    </description>
    <author email="email@myemail.com" href="http://whatever.com">
        HiltonSmythe Web Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="org.wbt11a.nativecamera" source="pgb" spec="0.1.4" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
    <plugin name="org.wbt11a.nativecamera" source="pgb" spec="0.1.4" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
    <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```

there is more but don't think there is a need to post the whole config

When i run cordova platform add iOS i just get these errors :

> Discovered plugin "org.apache.cordova.geolocation" in config.xml.
>   Adding it to the project Failed to restore plugin
>   "org.apache.cordova.geolocation" from config.xml. You might need to
>   try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.geolocation Discovered
>   plugin "org.apache.cordova.globalization" in config.xml. Adding it to
>   the project Failed to restore plugin
>   "org.apache.cordova.globalization" from config.xml. You might need to
>   try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.globalization Discovered
>   plugin "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" in config.xml. Adding it to
>   the project Failed to restore plugin "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser"
>   from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error:
>   Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser Discovered
>   plugin "org.apache.cordova.media" in config.xml. Adding it to the
>   project Failed to restore plugin "org.apache.cordova.media" from
>   config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error:
>   Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.media Discovered plugin
>   "org.apache.cordova.network-information" in config.xml. Adding it to
>   the project Failed to restore plugin
>   "org.apache.cordova.network-information" from config.xml. You might
>   need to try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for
>   GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.network-information
>   Discovered plugin "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" in config.xml.
>   Adding it to the project Failed to restore plugin
>   "org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" from config.xml. You might need to
>   try adding it again. Error: Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen Discovered
>   plugin "org.apache.cordova.vibration" in config.xml. Adding it to the
>   project Failed to restore plugin "org.apache.cordova.vibration" from
>   config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Error:
>   Registry returned 404 for GET on
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/org.apache.cordova.vibration

Am i doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You updated your cordova version I suppose.
Naming of the plugins changed after Cordova 5.0 and also where they are stored. You are using the new registry (npmjs.org), but the old plugin names: `org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser`

Re-add the plugins with the new naming convention, like: `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`